# How to check if user has valid Auth Session Firebase iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I wanna check if the user has still a valid session, before I present the Home View controller of my app. I use the latest Firebase API. I think if I use the legacy, I'll be able to know this.

Here's what I did so far:

- I posted my question on Slack community of Firebase, no one is answering. I found this one, but this is for Android: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=el#!topic/firebase-talk/4HdhDvVRqHc
- I tried reading the docs of Firebase for iOS, but I can't seem to comprehend it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth

I tried typing in Xcode like this:

```
FIRApp().currentUser()
FIRUser().getCurrentUser()
```

But I can't seem to find that getCurrentUser function.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users

Comment: wait, what? there's a guide? I didn't notice that "guide" tab, only the "reference" tab. Thank you so much! But is this applicable if the app only accepts 1 account, and many users will have to login that same account on the same app?

Comment: FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

Answer (score 31):

```
if FIRAuth.auth().currentUser != nil {
   presentHome()
} else {
   //User Not logged in
}
```

For updated SDK

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

}
```

Comment: this doesn't prove anything. `currentUser` refers to locally stored data

Comment: I don't know what you want me to say, this answer is 3 years old at this point. It was used like this in Firebase sample code ‍♂️

Answer (score 14):

**Updated answer**

Solution for latest Firebase SDK - [DOCS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#listen_for_authentication_state)

```
    // save a ref to the handler
    private var authListener: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    // Check for auth status some where
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        authListener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in

            if let user = user {
                // User is signed in
                // let the user in?

                if user.isEmailVerified {
                    // Optional - check if the user verified their email too
                    // let the user in?
                }
            } else {
                // No user
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove the listener once it's no longer needed
    deinit {
        if let listener = authListener {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(authListener)
        }
    }
```

**Original solution**

Solution in Swift 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            self.switchStoryboard()
        }
    }
}
```

Where `switchStoryboard()` is

```
func switchStoryboard() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NameOfStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerName") as UIViewController

    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[Source](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2)

Comment: that callback saves me lot of time, cause I'm not receiving any callbacks from AuthUI =/

Comment: None of the answers here are right. You have to use the reauth function from the Firebase API to refresh the auth token... otherwise you are just checking if the user exists in cache or in the backend service...

Answer (score 5):

Solution in Swift 4

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupLoadingControllerUI()
    checkIfUserIsSignedIn()
}

private func checkIfUserIsSignedIn() {

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {
            // user is signed in
            // go to feature controller 
        } else {
             // user is not signed in
             // go to login controller
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil {

   //user is logged in

    }else{
     //user is not logged in
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

While you *can* see if there is such a user using `Auth.auth().currentUser`, this will only be telling you if there **was** a user authenticated, regardless of whether that users account still exists or is valid.

---

#### Complete Solution

The real solution to this should be using `Firebase`'s re-authentication:

```
open func reauthenticate(with credential: AuthCredential, completion: UserProfileChangeCallback? = nil)
```

This assures (upon the launch of the application) that the previously signed in / authenticated user *still in fact* **is and can be** authenticated through Firebase.

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser    // Get the previously stored current user
var credential: AuthCredential
    
user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

Comment: I receive `Variable 'credential' used before being initialized`

Comment: That's because you never assigned a value to `credential` in the code above, you have to give `credential` a value before you do `user.reauthenticate`

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
FIRAuth.auth()!.addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
            // 2
            if user != nil {
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
}
```

Source: https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

Answer (score 0):

An objective-c solution would be (iOS 11.4):

```
[FIRAuth.auth addAuthStateDidChangeListener:^(FIRAuth * _Nonnull auth, FIRUser * _Nullable user) {
    if (user != nil) {
        // your logic
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

All the provided answers only check on `currentUser`. But you could check the auth session by simple user reload like below:

```
    // Run on the background thread since this is just a Firestore user reload, But you could also directly run on the main thread.

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { error in
            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Authentication Error
                    // Do the required work on the main thread if necessary 
                }
            } else {
                log.info("User authentication successfull!")
            }
        })
    }
```