# How would I be able to detect if the user still has an auth session in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was able to find this: [How to check if user has valid Auth Session Firebase iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738366/how-to-check-if-user-has-valid-auth-session-firebase-ios), but it wasn't able to answer my question.

**What I'm trying to do**: I know this will never happen unless the user deletes their own account, but would I know if the user still has an auth session?

For example, under the authentication tab, I deleted the entry that was created by the test user and even though I use these pieces of code:

in AppDelegate.swift:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
}
```

and in my main view controller:

```
private func checkIfSignedIn() {
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {
            // code to stay signed in
        } else {
            // code for dismissing the controller and moving to login controller
        }
    }
}
```

When I run erase the entry from the Authentication section of firebase console and re-run the app, the user is still logged in and still has a valid UID (I was able to print it to check).

The only time it detects when it should sign out and doesn't sign back in again is when I manually click the sign out button. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40276627/1500134

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `StateDidChangeListener`. Instead you're telling Firebase to call you when the authentication state changes, which may happen a few times when the page is being re-loaded.

When a page is getting loaded and there was previously a user signed in, the auth state may change a few times, while the client is figuring out if the user's authentication state it still valid. `Auth.auth().currentUser` will always return a valid user if you already signed in. so use it.

```
private func checkIfSignedIn() {
   if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      // code to stay signed in
   }else{
      // redirect to sign in page
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this is reliable because currentUser will be null as soon as the page loads until Firebase figures it out and populates the user.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user

I am not an IOS Dev but from what i read from the doc, it might look like there something missing in your code and it looks really familiar to what in the Stackoverflow answer pointed out by WillB at: [How can I detect if the user was deleted from Firebase auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252218/how-can-i-detect-if-the-user-was-deleted-from-firebase-auth/40276627#40276627)

Answer (score 0):

What were you trying to do with the code in your AppDelegate? Surely, if `currentUser` is `nil`, then you're already signed out, meaning that this code would never do anything?

If this is for testing-purposes, and you simply want to test the `listener`, then you need to be signed-in before signing out, I.E change it to `if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil` in AppDelegate.